Should I focus on CPU or GPU for my upgrade?
I want to upgrade my PC mainly focusing on heavily modded Minecraft. My current specs are:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950
Ram: 32.0GB Dual-Channel DDR4
MOTHERBOARD: B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC
POWER SUPPLY: Kolink Core RGB 500W

I was first thinking of getting a new GPU (probably the Gigabyte GeForce RTX 3070 8GB GDDR6 Gaming OC (rev. 2.0)) since the current one I have is very old, but, after some research I found out that Minecraft relies mainly on the CPU and not the GPU, unless I am running shaders. After scavaging the internet I found out that the AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D 4.2GHz with 8 cores AM5 is a pretty good upgrade (yes I am only thinking of AMD regarding the CPU). I don't have extensive knowledge about this stuff though and now I am worried about the GPU/CPU not being able to keep up with the CPU/GPU, respectively. I am also not sure about any of these two options being overkill since I mainly focus on Minecraft, but, I also want to be able to handle stuff like a giant Mangrove Swamp/Jungle, a big TNT explosion or a lot of entities, which cause me a bunch of lag with my current setup. Therefore, I am asking this question here so that I can get some info on the correct combination for my upgrade. I don't want to go too overkill, but, I also have 800 to 1000 euros to spend (in the Greek market).
Note: I am pretty sure that I will need to upgrade my motherboard and power supply with each one of those upgrades, although, I haven't really thought about this extensively yet.

You could probably use a 5800X3D in the motherboard you have already. Take a look at this CPU model and see if it's enough for you. I think it's still a very capable and relevant processor. If you save money by not needing to upgrade mobo & RAM then you'll have more to spend on a GPU too.

I'll also second a 5800X3D. Do you play with shaders normally? A GTX 950 is pretty underpowered (arguably even for vanilla, depending on your render settings); while a 3070 might be overkill, I'd probably upgrade regardless, and I would definitely upgrade if you're thinking of using shaders.

@JMY1000 I checked the 5800X3D out and I will probably go with this one plus the 3070 as I do have the money and want some decent render distance. I will probably need a new power supply though right?

Yeah I would probably get a new PSU too.

Upgrading PCs is always fun and one of my favorite things to do! So lets check out the options.

CPU Upgrade: AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D

The AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D boasts 8 cores and 16 threads, providing excellent performance for gaming and multitasking.
While Intel processors historically excel in single-core performance, the 7800X3D strikes a good balance between multi-core capabilities and single-core speed.
Ensure your motherboard supports the AM5 socket for this CPU.


GPU Upgrade: Gigabyte GeForce RTX 3070 8GB GDDR6 Gaming OC (rev. 2.0)

The RTX 3070 is a powerful GPU that handles Minecraft effortlessly, even with shaders.
It's also great for other games and tasks.
Confirm that your power supply (PSU) can handle the RTX 3070 (usually requires at least a 650W PSU).


Other Considerations:

RAM: Your current 32GB RAM should suffice for Minecraft. If you encounter issues, consider upgrading to faster RAM.
Storage: An SSD will improve overall system responsiveness and game loading times.
Motherboard and PSU: As you mentioned, upgrading these components is essential to support the new CPU and GPU.


Budget and Overkill:

With 800 to 1000 euros, you have a decent budget.
The combination of Ryzen 7 7800X3D and RTX 3070 strikes a balance between performance and cost.
Allocate some budget for a quality PSU and motherboard.



Edit: Forgot to mention the 5800xd isn't a slouch either, it's a very solid choice if you were to be on a tight budget a 3070 would definitely be the best route for upgrading.
